# JQuery/JS Markdown plugin?

Tags: jquery, formatting, markdown

I'm writing a chat app, and I'd like to add some simple functionality where users use markup to affect text formatting, like **bold** or *italics*. I'm envisioning this would be like how it is done on Google Talk or StackOverflow. Does JQuery have any plugins to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

stackoverflow is using WMD editor. You can use WMD editor code. It's written by javascript.

check

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

For WMD to HTML , you can use [ShowDown javascript](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown).

Github source (include showdown.js)

> http://github.com/derobins/wmd

Showdown usages

```
var text = "Markdown *rocks*.";
var converter = new Attacklab.showdown.converter();
var html = converter.makeHtml(text);
alert(html);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is now using [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) (as highlighted on the [old github page for their WMD conversion](https://github.com/cky/wmd)). You can find a short (and fairly old) example of usage [here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/showdown-javascript-jquery).

Answer (score 6):

It’s easy to [use Showdown with or without jQuery](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/showdown-javascript-jquery). Here’s a jQuery example:

```
// See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/showdown-javascript-jquery for a plain JavaScript version as well
$(function() {
 // When using more than one `textarea` on your page, change the following line to match the one you’re after
 var $textarea = $('textarea'),
     $preview = $('<div id="preview" />').insertAfter($textarea),
     converter = new Showdown.converter();
 $textarea.keyup(function() {
  $preview.html(converter.makeHtml($textarea.val()));
 }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I wrote a jQuery Markdown Plugin that uses the Showdown converter. It is intended for use as a client-side utility when your server is serving Markdown documents - presumably organized in some meaningful directory structure.

Links to other Markdown documents and images are resolved with respect to your document base directory and document directory structure. Transclusion is also supported using `{{include-this}}` style tags allowing you to create meta-documents composed of smaller chunks of Markdown or raw text.

Sample usage: `$(#mydiv).markdown('mybase/', 'mydir/mydoc.markdown');`

Please feel free to download and use without restriction at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/markdown.