# using markdown in project

Tags: c#, markdown

I am very unfamiliar with Mark down and how to apply it to a web form project and I was hoping for some advice.

I have a basic text box, multiline and with this text box I want to be able to apply markdown such as **bold** or *italic* by means of typing it out. I added MarkdownSharp.dll as a reference in my project.

I was thinking then of adding a label to my form with which I would like to display the markdown in a web format.How would I go about in doing this,for example? Basdically it needs similar functionality to this text box I am writing in.

Regards

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604576/jquery-js-markdown-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) plugin. Which is based on the Markdown code used here in Stackoverflow.