# Jsoup.clean, image src data:image/png lost

Tags: image, jsoup, src

String "unsafe" comes from contenteditable="true" div to where it was pasted as image from clipboard

```
// neeeds to be escaped. It is HTML5 valid
String unsafe = ""<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="">
"


org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.relaxed();   

whitelist.addEnforcedAttribute("a", "rel", "nofollow"); 

String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, whitelist);

//and safe becomes: "<img alt="">"
//entire src lost !?
```

Note: randome surrouning html has  no effect. Src is lost in any case.

Answer (score 4):

The basic problem here is that if one quick looks at **relaxed** here:
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#relaxed
assumes only tags are in, without attributes. Did not look into source, but here claims some attributes are also in: [How to make a Jsoup whitelist to accept certain attribute content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444156/how-to-make-a-jsoup-whitelist-to-accept-certain-attribute-content).
And image is also already in and src also.

the problem that causes my src to disapear is at

```
preserveRelativeLinks
```

Which is set to false,for relaxed, hidden somewhere in JSoup code
https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/333

--> should be set to true:

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.clean("<img src='imgFile.png' />","http://www.somedomain.com", Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true)));
```

Comment: `whitelist.addProtocols("img", "src", "http", "https", "data", "cid");` should be added as well

Answer (score 1):

This is how to allow basic text with inline images like `src="data:image/png;base64,..."`:

```
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic()
.addTags("img")
.addAttributes("img", "height", "src", "width")
.addProtocols("img", "src", "http", "https", "data"));
```

Comment: This worked for me - changing the `whitelist` to `safelist`