# Jsoup cleaning my html

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to learn how to use Jsoup cleaning HTML code.

I want to remove the `<body>` tag from this example but `<p>` tag must stay:

```
public class prb {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String i = "<p>Text 1234 <body>WOW</body> Text 1234</p><p>Text 1234</p>";

        System.out.println(getStringWithoutHtmlTags(i));
    }

    public static String getStringWithoutHtmlTags(String text) {
        Whitelist asd = new Whitelist();
        asd.addTags("<p>", "</p>");
        asd.removeTags("<body>, </body>");

        return Jsoup.clean(text, asd);
    }
}
```

But it removes all tags. The output is:

> Text 1234 WOW Text 1234 Text 1234

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake on writing the `tags`, because `asd.addTags("<p>", "</p>");` is very **heavy** because you have twice `p` and `<,>,/` are useless

So as the documentation says :

```
asd.addTags("p");
asd.removeTags("body");
```

---

More details on tags/attributes/procotols for WhiteList : [Jsoup whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444156/how-to-make-a-jsoup-whitelist-to-accept-certain-attribute-content#answer-24498013)